# PHP Sum integers in an array

Tags: php, arrays

How does one add all the integer values in an array? For example, if I have this array:

```
array(2) {
    ["cart_2"]=> int(5)
    ["cart_1"]=> int(3)
}
```

What should I use to display the sum of its values (8)?

Answer (score 1):

Using the PHP function [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) would do just that. The very definition of the function is "*Calculate the sum of values in an array*", which is exactly what you're looking for.

```
$arr = array("cart_2" => 5, "cart_1" => 3);

echo array_sum($arr);  // prints 8
```

This function can also deal with floats, such as `3.14` and `2.71` - so it doesn't have to be integers, as long as they are numbers. It will ignore any strings *that does not start with numbers* (so the value `2text` would add 2, but the string `text 2` would not), but you should note that each boolean true will add the value 1 to the sum.